# Magento 1.9.1 After change the order address from admin notification mail is not going to customer

Tags: email, magento, notifications

On Magento system, I have placed a 1 order for wholesale customer from the admin. The customer receives a mail of new order place. After placing the order I notice the shipping address which I have selected is wrong.

I edit the shipping address and check on all the 3 checkboxes (Recalculate, Notification[customize],confirm update) below the update button. I have written a note on Notification [customize] section also. After clicking on update the message display “Order update, not yet applied. Customer has been sent an email with a confirmation link. Updates will be applied after confirmation.”

But the customer didn’t get any mail related to address change. We have used mandrill for sending a mail. I have checked is mandrill outbound but seems that the mail is not triggered from the Magento. Other than this mail all the mail is going to customer. Can anyone please tell me what is the problem? Why the address change/notification mail is not triggered from Magento ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in this way by making a change in order.php go to this file-

```
public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php
```

create  directory structure like this, then copy and paste the file to the path below.

```
public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php
```

Find the below code in that file and Make a change in file from

```
$mailer->setQueue($emailQueue)->send();
```

to

```
$mailer->send();
```